# How to legally prevent notification get removed in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I'm working on an app and want to provide a shortcut of a function to user by adding a ongoing notification. It's a little bit like some of dictionary app doing that they provide a shortcut as notification for quick search.
The problem is even I have setOngoing(true) and setAutoCancel(false), it's still get removed once the app is closed from multitasking pane
The code I was using as below .

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "C1";
            String description = "C1 is C1";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }



NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("XXXX")
                .setContentText("XXXXXXXX")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true) 
                .setAutoCancel(false);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);

        // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_2, builder.build());
```

Comment: If the user wishes to remove the notification... why do you care?

Answer (score 1):

In Android 14, notification [is always dismissable by a user](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#non-dismissable-notifications).

Answer (score 0):

You can start a *foreground service* so your notification is persistent. You'll need to add the `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permission to your `manifest` and then build/start the service from your application. Then, set the notification from inside the service.

[The Android docs for foreground services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) have a good walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 13 (API level 33), the notification linked with a foreground service *can* be dismissed by users through a swipe gesture. Prior versions of Android does not allow notification dismissal until the foreground service is halted or removed from the foreground.

To make the notification non-dismissable by the user in API 33 and above, use the `Notification.Builder` and set the `setOngoing()` method to `TRUE` during creation.

Android Documentation:

- [Handle User Initiated Stop](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#handle-user-initiated-stop)
- [User Dismiss Notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#user-dismiss-notification)